# How do I share konsole profiles with other computers?

Tags: linux, profile, konsole

I work on several computers and have set them up similarly. Today I created a new Konsole profile on one computer and want to use the new profile on other computers without manually recreating the profile. (All these computers are running Fedora 24 and kde.)

Konsole profiles are actually files in the directory ~/.local/share/konsole with names like Shell.profile. I tried copying Shell.profile to Shell2.profile without making any changes to the copy. The command `konsole --profile=Shell2` works properly, but when I go to the Konsole menu Settings -> Manage Profiles, I don't see 'Shell2' as one of the options.

I also looked at the file ~/.config/konsolerc, and I saw that it has a section for my favorite profiles. I added 'Shell2' to this list, but I still don't see 'Shell2' as a choice from File -> New Tab or Settings -> Manage Profiles. (I have restarted Konsole multiple times and still don't see 'Shell2'.)

Does anyone know what I need to do to make 'Shell2' appear in these lists?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file you found is one part of it. The profiles and color scheme  files are in your local configuration folder:

```
~/.local/share/konsole
```

Comment: This directory lacks keybindings I configured in Konsole.

Answer (score 2):

Transfer the contents of `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/` to the destination computer. This worked for me from Konsole 2.14.2 to 16.12.2.

Comment: The directory ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/ was used by older versions of konsole. With a current version of konsole (I currently have 18.12.3), new profiles are created in ~/.local/share/konsole.